# Sencha Touch - this.getParent() returns Cannot call method 'getParent' of undefined

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to get parent component in View but always get this error:

`Cannot call method 'getParent' of undefined`

Here is the code:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.callParent();
    this.loadMates();
},
loadMates: function() {

    var store = Ext.create('App.store.user.Mates');
    store.getProxy().setExtraParam('userId', this.getParent().getUserId());
    this.setStore(store);
}
```

I've no idea why the initialized View is `undefined`. I've tried to push "this" as parameter without any success.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**:

I've found sth here:
[http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?174406-this.parent-and-this.getParent()-always-return-undefined-in-initialize](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?174406-this.parent-and-this.getParent%28%29-always-return-undefined-in-initialize)

Comment: That's a good find in the Sencha forums! You should add it as an answer and accept it so that others can find this info easier.

Comment: Well, it's just an explanation, not solution :) Check post below. If you're facing similar problem I'll try to help. Just use comments below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've moved all of the logic into Controller. In `refs` there is link to parent and actual view. Now I can access parent's attributes easily. Loading function is called right after the actual view has been pushed.